# Laptop keeps losing internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, router

I have an Asus K55A series laptop which keeps losing its internet connection but maintains the wireless connection. The only way to resolve this is to reboot the router which will restore the connection temporarily until it drops out again. This was happening initially on an approx. monthly basis but has now worsened to 3 times in the last hour!

The router is a TP-Link Model: TL-WR740N

Unfortunately I don't have an ethernet cable to check to connection when plugged into the router

The only change to the network of late is that I have visitors who are using their devices. No other device is experiencing the dropouts. The list of additional devices include:

- 1x lenovo thinkpad
- 1x Macbook Pro Retina
- 2x iPad minis
- 1x iPhone 5s
- 1x HTC One

What can I try to rectify the problem?

Edit: I've noticed I cannot connect to the router settings on that laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with an older 2 wire 2701.  I scoured the web for help and the only potential solution I found was in an ATT forum.  They advised to disable the MAC filtering. I went into the modem configuration and found mine was already disabled. So still no cure for me. Maybe this will work for you.  Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it is disabled for me too!